# Как использовать materialize в React?

Tags: reactjs, materialize-css

Скорее всего, мой вопрос слишком новичковый, но погуглив так и не смог найти ответ на него.

Я только начал изучать `React`, и конечно, хотелось бы использовать его со стильным-модным-молодежным `materialize`. Бегло изучив [getting started materializecss](https://materializecss.com/getting-started.html) (да, да, это тоже новинка для меня, до этого использовал только `Bootstrap` + `jQuery`), я понял что `materialize` аналогично `bootstrap` использует `jQuery` для своих интерактивных эффектов.

И пока я не начал конструировать велосипеды из костылей, а понимание как работает `React` еще не сложилось, прошу вас, подскажите как всё таки правильно подружить `React` и `Materialize` ?

Comment: Вот `materialize` для `React` https://material-ui.com/

Comment: @Vladimir, о даже так. Напишите в ответ, я думаю другим может быть полезно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`materialize` создал специальную библиотеку для `React` [material-ui.com](http://material-ui.com)